# Force the retrieval of a script file to block

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Im working on a greasemonkey script, which injects a block of code into the page. That code then creates a script tag directed to a 3rd party source using the following:

```
function injectThis(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://site.com/file.js";
    s.head.appendChild(s);

    // other code to be executed once the above file has finished downloading

}
```

Is there a way to make the engine block until the retrieval and processing of the script has completed?

A few notes:
1: A syncronized xhr is out of the question b/c it's cross domain
2: gm_xhr is out of the question due to the purpose of the script Im working on
3: Adding an event/callback in file.js to indicate loaded isn't a solution due to the same reason #2 isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not listen to the `onload` of the script tag, and then fire your other stuff afterward?
If you need old-IE support, you can also listen for `onreadystatechange`.

The only way you're going to cause a synchronous load is by using `.innerHTML` or, much worse, `document.write`.

Much better would be to set `script.onload = function () { callOtherStuff(); };`.

Comment: Putting the `other code` into an event listener for the file isn't an option either. I can't control the loading order of other Greasemonkey scripts. Im basically writing a small framework I plan to use throughout some of my GM scripts, and it needs to be loaded before the rest of those scripts are executed

Comment: @SReject Right, so that basically comes down to `.innerHTML += <script ...>`/`document.write("<script ...>");`, if you have no control over the contents of the other scripts, to define dependencies, have no control over the dynamic loading of the intended other scripts, etc...